# How to pick an app to allow mock locations programmatically on Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-settings

Prior to Marshmallow "Allow mock locations" option could be changed programmatically(requires root)

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 1);
```

But now this option is app specific, means you have to pick the mocker app in developer options.

Is there a way to change this settings (inserting my app to allowed list) programmatically ?

Answer (score 8):

No there is no way to give access to set the default mock location app. The most you can do is display a notification to user upon opening the app for the first time, giving them instructions on how this is done though the settings.

Note that for the user to do this, there is no need for root access, but rather [developer access](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/). This allows you to set the default mock location app.

Even the best mock location apps out in the market don't have this implemented by default. Hope this helps :)

--EDIT--

However, thre is a way to make this easier for the user to access. You can point the user to the actual screen where the mock-location app is set using the code below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

This points the user to the screen where the mock-location app is set.

Comment: First of all you made me sad :) But technically we let assume the app in system partition of a rooted device. And we know that default mock location app info is stored somewhere (settings.db ?), so after this point, we are not unable to set the default mocker app ?

Comment: Forwarding user to developer settings is known thing, so there is no something that makes me surprise in your edited answer and no somethings refers to my comment in the edited answer.